# Fetch all users and Groups from a site collection using c# client Object model

Tags: development, sharepoint-online

I want to fetch all groups and users (outside of the the sharepoint group) from a Site collection using C# client object model.
Currently i am bale to fetch all the groups and users inside those groups.
But if i open Site permissions, and if any users are given permission directly (without including in any groups), how do i retrieve these user's? Please suggest.

Answer (score 6):

`Web.SiteUsers` gives all users whether they are added in a group or added explicitly without being part of any group.

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("http://aissp2013:90"))
{               
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    UserCollection coll = web.SiteUsers;
    clientContext.Load(coll);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (User user in coll)
    {
        clientContext.Load(user.Groups);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        if (user.Groups.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(user.LoginName);
        }                    
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with this. But i do get many users which i am not able to see them on site permissions page.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, it will also show users which are added in groups.

Comment: Is there a way to get only the users who are added explicitly outside of any sharepoint groups?

Comment: See my updated answer. Just check the count of the number of groups for a user. If it is 0, that means user has been explicitly added.

Comment: is this possible using ECMA script or JSOM, for a  SP 2010 site collection and sub site